# Android / Java - ListView Populated with XML Data Using ArrayList: Only Displays First Item

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-listview, arraylist

I'm attempting to populate a ListView with XML Data by using an ArrayList - which I've been able to accomplish thus far - the issue is the ArrayList does not seem to populate the ListView with data beyond the first item in the listView and I'm unsure why.

### Screenshot

[image]

### XML Data:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<response>
<cmd>getVideos</cmd>
<success>1</success>
<NumberOfVideos>4</NumberOfVideos>
<Videos>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iPod</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/06087297988b.m4v
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_mpeg4</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/b5ed9e7100e2.mp4
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_sorenson</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/2a8e64b24997.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iTunes</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/6c7f65254aad.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
</Videos>
</response>
```

### CustomListViewAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cmd> {
    Activity context;
    List<Cmd> videos;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Cmd> videos) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item2, videos);
        this.context = context;
        this.videos = videos;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtSuccess;
        TextView txtCmd;
        TextView txtPrice;
    }

    public Cmd getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.success);
            holder.txtCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);

        holder.txtSuccess.setText(cmd.getSuccess());
        holder.txtCmd.setText(cmd.getCmd());
     // holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(cmd.getImageBitmap());
        holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoName() + "");

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity.java

```
public class SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements
OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    List<Cmd> videos = new ArrayList<Cmd>();

    CustomListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

    static final String URL = "http://mobile.example.com/api/xml.php?cmd=getVideos&username=fake&password=";
    public static final String LIBRARY = "Library";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parser_main);

        findViewsById();
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cmdList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        // task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    // private inner class extending AsyncTask
    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Cmd>> {
        private Activity context;

        public GetXMLTask(Activity context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(List<Cmd> videos) {
            listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, videos);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        }

        /*
         * uses HttpURLConnection to make Http request from Android to download
         * the XML file
         */
        private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Cmd> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            List<Cmd> videos = null;
            String xml = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
                videos = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);

                for (Cmd cmd : videos) {
                    String videoName = cmd.getVideoName();
                    // String getVideos = cmd.getVideos();
                    String getVideo = cmd.getVideo();
                    String getVideoURL = cmd.getVideoURL();
                    String getNumberOfVideos = cmd.getNumberOfVideos();

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

                    try {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                                new URL(videoName).openStream(), null,
                                bmOptions);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            // stream.close();
            return videos;
        }
    }
}
```

### Cmd.java

```
public class Cmd implements ListAdapter {
    private String success;
    private String cmd;
    List<Cmd> videos;
    private String video;
    private String numberofvideos;
    private String videoname;
    private String videourl;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    Context my_context;

   // private Bitmap imageBitmap;




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If convertView wasn't null it means we have already set it to our
        // list_item_user_video so no need to do it again
        if (convertView == null) {
            // This is the layout we are using for each row in our list
            // anything you declare in this layout can then be referenced below
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user_video,
                    parent, false);
        }
        // We are using a custom imageview so that we can load images using urls
        ImageView thumb = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userVideoThumbImageView);
        //thumb.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userVideoTitleTextView);
        TextView uploader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userVideouploaderTextView);

        TextView viewCount = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.userVideoviewsTextView);
        uploader.setText(videos.get(position).getTitle());
        viewCount.setText(videos.get(position).getviewCount() + " views");

        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);
        fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                        .getBackground()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(my_context.getResources()
                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.fav_up_btn1)
                                .getConstantState());

                // set the background
                fav_up_btn1
                .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                        : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
            }
        });

        // Get a single video from our list
        final Cmd video = videos.get(position);
        // Set the image for the list item
//  /   thumb.setImageDrawable(video.getThumbUrl());
        //thumb.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        // Set the title for the list item
        title.setText(video.getTitle());
        uploader.setText("by " + video.getUploader() + " |  ");

        return convertView;
    }

    public String getUploader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String getviewCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getTitle() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public String getCmd() {
        return cmd;
    }

    public void setCmd(String cmd) {
        this.cmd = cmd;
    }
    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String getNumberOfVideos() {
        return numberofvideos;
    }
    public void setNumberOfVideos(String numberofvideos) {
        this.numberofvideos = numberofvideos;
    }
    public List<Cmd> getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }
    public void setVideos(List<Cmd> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }
    public String getVideo() {
        return video;
    }
    public void setVideo(String video) {
        this.video = video;
    }
    public String getVideoName() {
        return videoname;
    }

    public void setVideoName(String videoname) {
        this.videoname = videoname;
    }
    public String getVideoURL() {
        return videourl;
    }

    public void setVideoURL(String videourl) {
        this.videourl = videourl;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return videos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public String getId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

### SAXXMLParser.java

```
public class SAXXMLParser {

    public static List<Cmd> parse(InputStream is) {
        List<Cmd> response = null;
        try {
            // create a XMLReader from SAXParser
            XMLReader xmlReader = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser()
                    .getXMLReader();
            // create a SAXXMLHandler
            SAXXMLHandler saxHandler = new SAXXMLHandler();
            // store handler in XMLReader
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(saxHandler);
            // the process starts
            xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(is));
            // get the `Video list`
            response = saxHandler.getResponse();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("XML", "SAXXMLParser: parse() failed");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return video list
        return response;
    }
}
```

### SAXXMLHandler.java

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private List<Cmd> videos;
    private String tempVal;
    // to maintain context
    private Cmd cmd;

    public SAXXMLHandler() {
        videos = new ArrayList<Cmd>();
    }

    public List<Cmd> getResponse() {
        return videos;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal = "";
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cmd")) {
            // create a new instance of cmd
            cmd = new Cmd();

        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            // add it to the list
            videos.add(cmd);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            cmd.setSuccess(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("numberofvideos")) {
            cmd.setNumberOfVideos(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            cmd.setVideos(videos);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
            cmd.setVideo(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videoname")) {
            cmd.setVideoName(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videourl")) {
            cmd.setVideoURL(tempVal);

        }
    }
}
```

### parser_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button" />

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/cmdList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

### XML Screenshot

[image]

P.S.

If any additional information is required - please let me know (I will be at my desk working on this for the next few hours and will gladly answer any questions and accept any answers promptly)

Comment: I suspect it's something in your layout_width or layout_height for either the ListView or the ViewGroup it's contained within. Can you post your layout XML for your activity?

Comment: Also, have you considered using ListActivity as the parent class of your SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity?

Comment: I posted it (I suppose I could/should - but I'd like to figure out why it isn't working before I consolidate it!) :)

Comment: Have you debugged your asynctask? How many items are in `List<Cmd> videos` on post execute?

Comment: videos=ArrayList Array=Object[12]: null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null


:(

Comment: What is the size of the list that `SAXXMLParser.parse(stream)` returns? Also in the `for (Cmd cmd : videos)` loop in your doInBackground you define a number of variables that you dont do anything with..that looks like it could cause some unexpected behaviour to you

Comment: I'll check (Note: -  in my doInBackground: xml = getXmlFromUrl(url); gives me all the XML data I'm looking for)

Comment: Thats good - can you check my previous comment and let me know the results

Comment: SAXXMLParser.parse(stream) is Cmd, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null

Comment: That is no good - can you post the code for that class please

Comment: Your layout XML looks fine. Are you totally sure that all of the data is being parsed correctly? Maybe you could Log.d() it and make sure. The reason I ask is that it looks like the last item in the XML is the first one being displayed, and no others. So maybe only the last item is actually in the collection. Just a thought.

Comment: posted the Cmd class as well as my parser and handler (thank you for your help with this - seriously!)

Comment: Ah sorry i meant the code for SAXXMLParser, the bug lies in these 2 lines `InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
                videos = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);` and im guessing its the second one that causes it so something is going wrong in your parser

Comment: Ok thanks! (I think we're getting VERY close!) I debugged it and xml.getBytes() contains the XML data but videos is still null (I'm looking at my parser class - but I'm having trouble figuring out exactly what I need to do to fix it)

Comment: How often is this if condition true? Once? `if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            // add it to the list
            videos.add(cmd);` i dont understand a whole lot of your code but it seems in this method `endElement` the list is getting populated - maybe you forgot some videos.add statements?

Comment: qName = "cmd" count = 3

and I checked the value of cmd in: videos.add(cmd); and it's showing as null across the board

Comment: I tried adding them to see if it would make a difference... Does this look correct to you?

http://pastebin.com/2KW8vyTt

Comment: What i mean is at the moment you only add the cmd to the `videos` list if `qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")`  in all other cases you modify the cmd but you dont actually add it to the list, is that how is it supposed to be? I would think not..

Comment: Correct! (We need to add everything to the list!) So I imagine it would work something like this?: http://pastebin.com/JZW7xJxT

Actually - I just tested it - it works!!

Thank you!!!

Comment: Alright excellent. Im gonna post it as an answer, do me a favour and accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SAXXMLHandler.java**'s `endElement()` method you only add the cmd to the videos list if     `qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")`.

In all other cases you modify the cmd but you dont actually add it to the list. You want to add a `videos.add(cmd)` statement in the `else if` blocks as well so all the cmd's get added to the list.

This mistake right here is the cause of your `List<Cmd> videos`  only having one item and thus only showing one item in your listview.

Comment: Thank you sir! 

Your assistance is/was greatly appreciated!

Comment: One more question regarding this... the listView is populated now - but it is the same data repeated over and over (instead of each unique  item in the XML) do you have any idea what I might be able to do to resolve that - or should I start a new thread regarding the issue?

Comment: I think the problem lies in **SAXXMLHandler.java** once more. You create a `new Cmd` only in `startElement()` (i think that only happens once which means you re use the same object every time). But as i mentioned earlier i dont quite understand the flow of your program so it could be something else ;-)

Comment: It is based on this tutorial/example... (let me know if that helps - I'm going to see what I can do to fix it and if not... you'll probably see a cry for help in a new post!)

Thanks again...

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/

Comment: I checked the link but thats a little too much code to dive into right now - should post a new question!

Comment: No worries... if you get some free time the new post is located here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614684/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-displays-same-data-over-and-over

Comment: Just accept the answer and move on, no need to start a conversation on an entirely different topic..