# Android: Simple XML SAX Parser - Displays Same Data Over and Over

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, sax

I've created an XML parser which populates a listView with data obtained from an XML file. The problem is for some reason the listView shows the same data over and over instead of unique data for each listView item.

I'm not sure exactly what is causing this issue - any insight is greatly appreciated.

### Screenshot:

[image]

### XML Data:

```
<response>
<cmd>getVideos</cmd>
<success>1</success>
<NumberOfVideos>4</NumberOfVideos>
<Videos>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iPod</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/06087297988b.m4v
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_mpeg4</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/b5ed9e7100e2.mp4
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_sorenson</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/2a8e64b24997.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
<Video>
<VideoName>sample_iTunes</VideoName>
<VideoDesc/>
<VideoUrl>
http://mobile.example.com/api/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/01/api/1/6c7f65254aad.mov
</VideoUrl>
<VideoTags/>
</Video>
</Videos>
</response>
```

### Example/Tutorial:

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xml-sax-parser-tutorial/

### SAXXMLHandler.java

```
     public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private List<Cmd> videos;
    private String tempVal;
    // to maintain context
    private Cmd cmd;

    public SAXXMLHandler() {
        videos = new ArrayList<Cmd>();
    }

    public List<Cmd> getResponse() {
        return videos;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // reset
        tempVal = "";
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Video")) {
            // create a new instance of cmd
            cmd = new Cmd();

        }
    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            // add it to the list
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            cmd.setSuccess(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("numberofvideos")) {
            cmd.setNumberOfVideos(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            cmd.setVideos(videos);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
            cmd.setVideo(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videoname")) {
            cmd.setVideoName(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videourl")) {
            cmd.setVideoURL(tempVal);
            videos.add(cmd); //You only need store an instance of your Cmd 
        }
      }
    }
```

### CustomListViewAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cmd> {
    Activity context;
    List<Cmd> videos;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity context, List<Cmd> videos) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item2, videos);
        this.context = context;
        this.videos = videos;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtSuccess;
        TextView txtCmd;
        TextView txtPrice;
    }

    public Cmd getItem(int position) {
        return videos.get(position);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtSuccess = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.success);
            holder.txtCmd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cmd);
            holder.txtPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Cmd cmd = (Cmd) getItem(position);


        holder.txtSuccess.setText(cmd.getSuccess());
            holder.txtCmd.setText(cmd.getCmd());
         //   holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(cmd.getImageBitmap());
            holder.txtPrice.setText(cmd.getVideoName() + "");

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

### SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity.java

```
public class SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements
OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    Button button;
    ListView listView;
    List<Cmd> videos = new ArrayList<Cmd>();

    CustomListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;

    static final String URL = "http://mobile.example.com/api/xmlrpc.php?cmd=getVideos&username=fake&password=credential";
    public static final String LIBRARY = "Library";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.parser_main);

        findViewsById();
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    private void findViewsById() {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cmdList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask(this);
        // task.execute(new String[] { URL });
    }

    // private inner class extending AsyncTask
    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Cmd>> {
        private Activity context;

        public GetXMLTask(Activity context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(List<Cmd> videos) {
            listViewAdapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context, videos);
            listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        }

        /*
         * uses HttpURLConnection to make Http request from Android to download
         * the XML file
         */
        private String getXmlFromUrl(String urlString) {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer("");
            try {
                InputStream stream = null;
                URL url = new URL(urlString);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
                httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConnection.connect();

                if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();

                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(stream));
                    String s = "";
                    while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        output.append(s);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Cmd> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            List<Cmd> videos = null;
            String xml = null;
            for (String url : urls) {
                xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
                videos = SAXXMLParser.parse(stream);

if ( videos == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Videos is null!)",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
                for (Cmd cmd : videos) {
                    String videoName = cmd.getVideoName();
                    // String getVideos = cmd.getVideos();
//                    String getVideo = cmd.getVideo();
//                    String getVideoURL = cmd.getVideoURL();
//                    String getNumberOfVideos = cmd.getNumberOfVideos();
//
//                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
//                    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//                    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
//
//                    try {
//                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
//                                new URL(videoName).openStream(), null,
//                                bmOptions);
//                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    } catch (IOException e) {
//                        e.printStackTrace();
//                    }
                }
            }
            // stream.close();
            return videos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're only creating one instance of `cmd` when the element's name is "cmd", and then keep adding it over and over.

Comment: Is there any reason why you create cmd in startElement() rather than endElement()?   The code would be clearer if new cmd() happened in endElement (you wouldn't need the member variable -- it would be local)   This would make it much less likely that you would forget to create a new one when you needed to.

Comment: @323go - how might I avoid doing that and create a unique item each time?

Comment: @DaleWilson - I should add it in the beginning of it like this, correct?  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
     cmd = new Cmd();

Comment: You can follow the advice of @Elenasys, who expanded on my comment.

Comment: Ok - I'm still having trouble with his answer. : ( 
(only every 3rd item in the listView displays the VideoName all others appear null )
i.stack.imgur.com/gBKQq.png

Comment: Any ideas? I'm still stumped...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the return of your doinbackground, here - `return videos;`, does videos contain what you expect it to?  By the way, your app will still crash is videos if null (e.g., if your WiFi is off).  You should use `if(videos!=null){....}else{.....}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating only one instance of `Cmd()` that is overriding itself, because you have only one `<cmd>` element.

Change:

```
 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cmd")) {
            // create a new instance of cmd
            cmd = new Cmd();

        }
```

to:

```
 if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Video")) {
            // create a new instance of cmd
            cmd = new Cmd();

        }
```

You need to create an instance of `Cmd()` when your parser read every `<Video>` element.

and change your `endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)` method to:

```
  public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            // add it to the list
        /*} else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            cmd.setSuccess(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("numberofvideos")) {
            cmd.setNumberOfVideos(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videos")) {
            cmd.setVideos(videos);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
            cmd.setVideo(tempVal);*/
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videoname")) {
            cmd.setVideoName(tempVal);
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("videourl")) {
            cmd.setVideoURL(tempVal);
            videos.add(cmd); //You only need store an instance of your Cmd 
        }
      }
```

Comment: it is now crashing on the line: for (Cmd cmd : videos) { in SAXParserAsyncTaskActivity (after making the change suggested above)

Comment: Is your Wifi turned off again?  As people have said before, you MUST test if `videos` is null before you try to us it.

Comment: #Fail (yes - it was) Ok. So now it's working... sort of (only every 3rd item in the listView displays the VideoName all others appear null )

Comment: OK my friend.  I will ignore your questions from now unless, you check `videos == null` before you try to use it and do something with the exception you catch instead of printing the stack trace and ignoring it.  Sorry, but if you won't take advice, I am not prepared to offer it. Have fun, and good luck.

Comment: inside your doInBackground() method don´t need this  "for (String url : urls) {", you are using only one .xml

Comment: Apologies @Simon - I added     if ( videos == null) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Videos is null!)",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 
                }

Comment: What do you suggest I do with the exception? (I really appreciate your help and have no problem following your suggestions)

Comment: I still don't know what to do about every third item having data... (help!) : )

Comment: @ValdimárrOlaf With the exception, you should do whatever makes sense for your app if you are not able to get a connection to the server, or there is some other problem getting the query results.  That way, everyone, including you, will know that there is an problem instead of seeing an empty list view and wondering what happened.

Comment: Ok - I'm going to add a toast to my exceptions (I just wanted to run it by you first incase you had another suggestion) 


While I'm doing that... any ideas for what might be causing every 3rd listing to display null?

Comment: Simply changing that line results in this (I was able to resolve the previous force close by removing the toast temporarily) now I am able to toggle between the change you most recently suggested and the previous implementation to cause / prevent this force close: (I'll update my source above now) http://pastebin.com/bGBiziy5

Comment: you don´t have to change just a line, you have to replace all the method  endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)

Comment: I did I copy and pasted your entire method (and updated my source above to reflect it)

Comment: It looks like the logcat is pointing to cmd.setSuccess(tempVal); (line 47 in SAXXMLHandler)

as the source of the crash (after making that change) 

http://pastebin.com/VPHjE6j3

Comment: It seems as if it really wants the  videos.add(cmd); after cmd.setSuccess(tempVal);

Comment: thats the exception, < success> and < NumberOfVideos> aren't nested inside < videos>, change the method and it will work now:)